# What to do to notify search engines of of a cms switch Wordpress->Drupal?

Tags: seo, cms

I'm switching a website from wordpress to drupal.
The structure and content of the new website will be slightly different so i'd like to know what are the things i need to do in order to notify the search engines of these changes so that they reindex everything?

Any idea on how long it usually take for the results to reflect the new content?

Answer (score 1):

The search engines don't care about your CMS. There's nothing special you need to do. 
Next time they crawl your site, they'll hit some 404s and eventually drop those pages, and find some new ones, just like any other time. That's the more or less no-effort approach.

If you've done extensive and ideally predictable rearranging of your URLs, you should set up 301 redirects for as many of them as possible. You'll find plenty of examples for various common patterns in the [301-redirect](/questions/tagged/301-redirect) tag. That will explicitly tell them that those pages have moved from X to Y location, rather that simply being unavailable at the moment, and help indexes get updated faster, etc.

Comment: Adding to what Su' has said, the time it takes for the content to be re-indexed isn't known. While Google will probably be at your site the same day you switch the time they put the updated content in their index and cache servers could all vary from minutes, hours, days, or weeks. Re-generate your site-map and submit it again to Google and Bing webmaster tools being sure to remove the old one will help. Having an HTML sitemap is also suggested by Google.